# Game Engines that use PHP for scripting?

Tags: php, c++, game-engine

There is a variety of Game Engines out on the market, free as commercial. Most of them also have at least one scripting language implemented to enhance the gameplay either by the whole game is built up on and around it, or for external modding. Some well known scripting languages are *Lua*, *Python*, *Ruby*, *TorqueScript* and *AngelScript*. I myself are aware of the first and fourth one and use both of them frequently when I have to. Those Game Engines built up around the scripting language uses mostly *PHP*, *ASP* or *JavaScript* (And in most cases a database language for storage purposes). These are whole Game Engines that relies on the scripting language to the fullest.

Some libraries uses PHP to enhance the interface like Qt.

However, those Game Engines for PHP is made to be used only along with a web browser connecting to the server that uses that script. What I was looking for is a stand-alone Game Engine that uses C or C++ in its core and PHP as a scripting language.

**Does it exist a stand-alone Game Engine that uses PHP for scripting?**

**Is there any possibility to create this engine or is the PHP source too tightened to a web server like Apache?**

Comment: I hope nothing like this exists... Why not try Lua? It's always good to learn a new language.

Comment: What kind of game engine? For what kind of game?

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark The danger of learning new languages is the sadness caused [by moving back and] no longer being able to use them ... :)

Comment: @pst: That's especially true if the language awaiting you back is PHP :)

Comment: If you're looking to use a readable high-level language (like PHP) for scripting, I'd suggest either [Python](http://python.org/) or [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/). Python has been used in quite a few high profile games (BF2, EVE Online, Civ IV etc.)

Comment: @nomaD: How exactly is PHP more readable or high-level than Lua?

Comment: I never said it is - Lua would be the best option, but in the question it appeared that there would be some reason behind him not wanting to use it

Comment: This question was asked as I was curious if it was viable. Sure, 6 years later, I do know it is a really bad design choice, but it doesn't mean it will not exist. I do enjoy getting different perspectives on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I google'd it and found these two: http://raydium.org/ and http://engine.nowhere-else.org/

Comment: So, why did I get a down vote? I explicitly answered the question that was asked and informed the OP of where I found the answer so he/she may refer to such tools in the future.

Comment: generally link-only answers are frowned upon (i was not the down voter)

Comment: I understand and, generally, agree with that. However, given the question is a "google for me" type of question, I would think it fits the bill quite nicely.

Comment: Excuse me for not being specific of what I was looking for. These links you gave me the first one is correct, but the other one, correct me if I'm wrong, is a web browser game. I would however ask you to give additional information over the engines.